# Meteor prevent browser default alert upon submit

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a specific unified alert package that displays alerts/notifications upon submission in a cohesive way across web browsers. I am finding that after submit in the Autoform.hook(), the default browser alert format also fires. Any help to prevent the default browser alter from firing would be appreciated.
[image]

I have tried using an event handler:event.preventDefault();

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  'edit-form': {
    onSuccess: function (operation, result, template) {
      IonPopup.alert({
    title: 'Saved Succesfully!',
    subTitle: 'Please Click OK to go back',
    onOk: function()
        {
          Session.set("editingReqEvent", null);
          Router.go('calendar');
        }
  });
},

onError: function(operation, error, template) {
  IonPopup.alert({title: 'Save Unsucessful!', subTitle: 'Please go back and check entries'});
  console.log(error);
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: The code you have shown merely stops the default submit event from firing. Show more code please.

Comment: Yes you are correct. The problem is after the submit. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the default alert event, or overwrite it just with plain js:

```
window.alert = function() {};
```

Comment: this was the answer as the submit button went to another post submit processing .js file - Autoform.hooks({}), to which I just used your original and edited answer right before the hook. window.alert = function() {
  return false;
}; Thank you!